# Getting the column totals in a 2D array but it always throws FormatException using C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I am planning to get an **array of the averages of each column**.

But my app crashes at `sum[j] += int.Parse(csvArray[i,j]);` due to a **FormatException**. I have tried using Convert.ToDouble and Double.Parse but it still throws that exception.

The increments in the `for loop` start at **1** because `Row 0 and Column 0` of the CSV array are **strings** (names and timestamps). For the `divisor` or `total count of the fields that have values per column`, I only count the fields that are `not BLANK`, hence the **IF** statement. I think I need help at handling the exception.

Below is the my existing for the method of getting the averages.

```
public void getColumnAverages(string filePath)
        {

            int col = colCount(filePath);
            int row = rowCount(filePath);

            string[,] csvArray = csvToArray(filePath);
            int[] count = new int[col];
            int[] sum = new int[col];
            double[] average = new double[col];

            for (int i = 1; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
                {
                    if (csvArray[i,j] != " ")
                    {
                        sum[j] += int.Parse(csvArray[i,j]);
                        count[j]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < average.Length; i++)
            {
                average[i] = (sum[i] + 0.0) / count[i];
            }

            foreach(double d in average)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(d);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have uploaded the [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ5wr0I2306a2c3LVRVdTl4bUk/view?usp=sharing) that I use when I test the prototype. It has `BLANK` values on some columns. Was my existing **IF statement** unable to handle that case?

There are also entries like this `1.324556-e09`due to the number of decimals I think. I guess I have to trim it in the `csvToArray(filePath)` method or are there other efficient ways? Thanks a million!

Comment: So what is the value of `csvArray[i,j]` at the point that it fails?

Comment: Its because failed to parse the string as integer, Please include the sample data populated by csvToArray in `csvArray`

Comment: I would also suggest checking for blank with `if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(csvArray[i,j]))`, and you can use `int.TryParse` to be able to handle if it isn't a valid number at all

Comment: @musefan Hi I have added a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @un-lucky I've checked manually, csvArray[1,1] value is "23313". I am not sure why it does not parse.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show the values that are being used though

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan When I run through your method with a static CSV array that I've created I receive no errors and the averages are returned as expected. What musefan suggests about checking for whitespace could be a good start. If you could provide full details of files and code It might be possible for use to do some debugging but without this data it's only possible to speculate on potential formatting errors

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan Could you maybe just provide the CSV file?

Comment: @DanGardner Hi Dan! I have included the link to the CSV file in the question and my current findings when I investigated the file's content. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few problems with your code. The main reason for your format exception is that after looking at your CSV file your numbers are surrounded by quotes. Now I can't see from your code exactly how you convert your CSV file to an array but I'm guessing that you don't clear these out - I didn't when I first ran with your CSV and experienced the exact same error.

I then ran into an error because some of the values in your CSV are decimal, so the datatype `int` can't be used. I'm assuming that you still want the averages of these columns so in my slightly revised verion of your method I change the arrays used to be of type `double`.

AS @musefan suggested, I have also changed the check for empty places to use the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method.

Finally when you output your results you receive a `NaN` for the first value in the averages column, this is because when you don't take into account that you never populate the first position of your arrays so as not to process the string values. I'm unsure how you'd best like to correct this behaviour as I'm not sure of the intended purpose - this might be okay - so I've not made any changes to this for the moment, pop a mention in the comments if you want help on how to sort this!

So here is the updated method:

```
public static void getColumnAverages(string filePath)
{

    // Differs from the current implementation, reads a file in as text and
    // splits by a defined delim into an array
    var filePaths = @"C:\test.csv";
    var csvArray = File.ReadLines(filePaths).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();

    // Differs from the current implementation
    var col = csvArray[0].Length;
    var row = csvArray.Length;

    // Update variables to use doubles
    double[] count = new double[col];
    double[] sum = new double[col];
    double[] average = new double[col];
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    for (int i = 1; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
        {
            // Remove the quotes from your array
            var current = csvArray[i][j].Replace("\"", "");

            // Added the Method IsNullOrWhiteSpace
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current))
            {
                // Parse as double not int to account for dec. values
                sum[j] += double.Parse(current);
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < average.Length; i++)
    {
        average[i] = (sum[i] + 0.0) / count[i];
    }

    foreach (double d in average)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(d + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding the file path, I used the **FileUpload** control in Web Forms since I have to upload it into the server. I think I am seeing a **limitation** after being able to get the array of averages. In the existing system, it searches for the `specific average` by the **String columns** in the first row. Could you help me think of a workaround for that?

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan I'm not sure that I fully understand the issue you've got, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi, after hours of coding at work today, everything works perfectly fine now. I somehow figured it out. I used a `dictionary` to get the column average of specific column headers. The lessons here would stick with me forever. Thanks a million! :)

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan Great! Glad it helped! If you reckon my answer answered your question, could you mark it as correct, thanks :)